# HTTP 404 error while connecting to mysql localhost

Tags: java, mysql, authentication, database-connection

I am trying to make a login form but my code shows http 404 error and is unable to connect to the mysql database. I am unable to figure the problem. Please look at the code and help me.

It also shows this error-
port 8080 reqrd by tomcat is already in use

DataBase Connection File

```
package connection;

import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;

public class DataCon 
{
  Connection con;

 public Connection getConnection1()
{
   try
 {
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance;
 con  = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/sumanDB","crime", "crime");

}
catch(Exception e)
{
   e.toString();
}
return con;

}
public void close(Connection con)
    {
      try{
           con.close();
      }catch(Exception e1)
        {}
    }
}
```

Validate.jsp File

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*"  %>
<%@ page import="connection.DataCon" %>

<%

   Connection con=null;
   Statement st=null;
   ResultSet rs=null;
   DataCon ds =new DataCon();
   String uname=request.getParameter("UserName");
   String pass=request.getParameter("Password");
   System.out.println(uname);
   System.out.println(pass);

     try{
           con=ds.getConnection1();
           st=con.createStatement();
           rs=st.executeQuery("select * from login_master where LOGIN_USER_NAME='"+uname+"'");
           System.out.println("rs"+rs);
            while(rs.next())
         {
                System.out.println("inside while");
                String user1=rs.getString(1);
                String password=rs.getString(5);
                System.out.println(user1);
                System.out.println(password);
                if(uname.equals(user1)&&pass.equals(password))
             {

                         System.out.println("inside if");
                         System.out.println(password);
                         String profile=rs.getString(2);
                         if(pass.equals(password))
                         {
                               System.out.println("inside pass equal");
                              if(profile.equals("PF1"))
                                  response.sendRedirect("adminzone.jsp");
                              else if(profile.equals("PF2"))
                                    response.sendRedirect("invgzone.jsp");
                              else if(profile.equals("PF3"))
                                    response.sendRedirect("writerzone.jsp");
                          }
                          else
                                    response.sendRedirect("Login.jsp");


             }//if
             else
                 response.sendRedirect("Login.jsp?msg='Incorrect Username or Password - Re-Check '");
         }//while

     }catch(Exception e){}

     con.close();
     %>
```

Comment: HTTP 404 is nothing to do with your database access, 404 is Apache saying I cannot find the page you are requesting!

Comment: Have a look at `/var/log/apache2/access.log` and `/var/log/apache2/error.log`.